# Solving a logarithmic equation with variables on each side

Tags: calculus, logarithms, analyticity

Okay, so while doing a problem for my calculus class I was required to graph two functions in order to see where they intersect, as according to my teacher there is no way to solve it analytically.

This really bothers me and there must be a way to solve it. I did research online to try to solve it, but I had no idea where to even start.

Here is the equation.

```
y = ln(5 - y)
```

Comment: So, what are the two functions?

Comment: This is a transcendental equation which doesn't seem to be solvable in terms of a finite number of elementary functions. If you like, this could be turned into an implicit function.

Comment: you will need a numerical method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this one you need Lambert's Omega function which is defined as:

$$W(z)e^{W(z)}=z$$

Your equation can be written as:

$x=\ln(5-x)$

$e^x=5-x$

$e^x+x=5$

Which solution is $x=5-W(e^5)$

Comment: Okay, thanks very much and that makes some sense, but how do you calculate W(e^5)?

Comment: @HenriSchmidt I was about to give some explicit formula to compute $W(x)$ but I think they are too much complicated for a non-expert in calculus so the only thing I can tell is to use an online calculator. Sorry.

Comment: If interested, see [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog/) for formulas